# How to Change GTK Themes in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, themes, gtk

It has never been a problem to me before, but now, within Ubuntu 18.04, it is not working for me any more.

Basically, I'm following,
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-change-ubuntu-theme/

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
gnome-tweaks &
```

[image]

However, flipping through the Themes in the "Applications" drop down has no effects at all. So,

- How to Change GTK Themes in Ubuntu? (It is GTK2 Theme that I'm especially interested in, and having difficulties with)
- And ultimately, how to change GTK Theme on command line?

PS,

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

This is a minimum installation machine started from net-install, so I need to install packages before using them.

PPS

I saw the following message when starting `gnome-tweaks`, might that be the culprit? How to fix it if so?

```
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
```

Comment: Have you also installed `gnome-shell-extensions` and enabled User themes, as in your link?

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. So I installed `gnome-shell-extensions` (and the 80 new packages that comes with it) , but I'm still seeing the `WARNING : Shell not installed or running`. One thing different is that I also see `WARNING : Error detecting shell` now. Moreover, while trying to change GTK Theme on command line myself, I've also installed over 20~30 packages. All these make the solution to change GTK Theme on command line more appealing to me.

Comment: Please reboot a couple of times before trying anything. What happens if you run tweaks with or without sudo? Try also to run it in the Alt+F2 command line.